# AWS DMS cannot connect to destination in Replication instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate a DB instance to an Aurora instance on AWS
I have set up the aurora db correctly, I can connect to it with my client...
In addition I have connected using Amazon Schema Conversion Tool and transferred the schema over - the tables all show up in the aurora db.

When I try to set up a replication instance
I get this:

```
Test Endpoint failed: 
Application-Status: 1020912
Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider Network error has occurred
Application-Detailed-Message: 
    RetCode: SQL_ERROR 
    SqlState: 08001 
    NativeError: 101 
    Message: [unixODBC]timeout expired ODBC general error.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your security group for the DB instance allow access for the DMS instance to connect?

Comment: Ah quasar, good question - here it get interesting, and looses me a bit.
AWS automatically set up a security groups for me when I started creating the instance....the inbound rule has the aurora (postgres) IP the outbound is open to all...in the vps security groups of my replication instance - it shows "rds-launch-wizard" ) which IS the security group and it IS selected ...but it also has "launch-wizard-1"..."launch-wizard-5"

Comment: I only have one VPC, so I cant be selecting the 'wrong' one

Comment: I would add port 5432 with the source of the DMS security group on both the RDS instance and the Aurora PG instance.